# Does posting data to iframe is sync or async?

Tags: javascript, iframe, submit, http-post

Does posting data to iframe is sync or async?

I have iframe and a form where the form.target=iframe

when I call to form.submit() what happen behind the scene? is it sync or async?

Answer (score -1):

In terms of the JS execution, I think it is synchronous. Even though the on pager behaviour might feel more like more of an async 'style' to the user because of the iframe

Should be quite easy for you to test though! ;-)

What is your use case that makes you ask the question?

Comment: does the next line after the 'form.submit()' runs only after the browser receives an HTTP response?

Comment: Test it! set an alert() or console.log() to fire immediately after and see what happens :o)